# How do I get switchable graphics to work on my Samsung RF711 With Intel HD & GeForce 540M Graphics cards on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS

Tags: nvidia, xorg, nvidia-optimus, hybrid-graphics, nvidia-prime

I have an Samsung RF711 Intel Core i7 laptop, running Ubuntu 14.04 LTS 64 bit. This comes with two graphics cards - the Intel one (which runs by default) and an Nvidia GeForce GT 540M (which I have never managed to get working on Ubuntu).

I tried various configurations with bumblebee but all ultimately failed when I tried to use optirun (I have seen an error like "unable to allocate software rendering cache" a few times in the Xorg log).

I had another attempt with nvidia-prime this morning. Firstly, I ensured that no bumblebee packages were installed, and I ran

```
sudo apt-get purge nvidia*
```

to remove any installed nvidia packages. I then did

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure lightdm
```

to ensure lightdm was the default, then

```
sudo apt-get install nvidia-331
```

which installed the 331 drivers, nvidia-prime, nvidia settings etc.

After rebooting, I enter low graphics mode. From here, the only way I've managed to get back to the desktop is to remove the nvidia packages using

```
sudo apt-get purge nvidia*
```

and reboot. This restores the laptop to how it was initially, of course.

Here is the output of lspci | grep 3D

```
01:00.0 3D controller: NVIDIA Corporation GF108M [GeForce GT 540M] (rev a1)
```

and here is the Xorg log (I had to remove some lines to cut down the characters - I have indicated where with **********removed*************)

```
[    45.605] 
X.Org X Server 1.15.1
Release Date: 2014-04-13
[    45.605] X Protocol Version 11, Revision 0
[    45.605] Build Operating System: Linux 3.2.0-37-generic x86_64 Ubuntu
[    45.605] Current Operating System: Linux ant-RF711 3.13.0-24-generic #46-Ubuntu SMP Thu Apr 10 19:11:08 UTC 2014 x86_64
[    45.605] Kernel command line: placeholder root=UUID=abdf0144-3ec5-4430-bb8f-d3deca65e960 ro quiet splash
[    45.606] Build Date: 16 April 2014  01:36:29PM
[    45.606] xorg-server 2:1.15.1-0ubuntu2 (For technical support please see http://www.ubuntu.com/support) 
[    45.606] Current version of pixman: 0.30.2
[    45.606]    Before reporting problems, check http://wiki.x.org
to make sure that you have the latest version.
[    45.606] Markers: (--) probed, (**) from config file, (==) default setting,
(++) from command line, (!!) notice, (II) informational,
(WW) warning, (EE) error, (NI) not implemented, (??) unknown.
[    45.606] (==) Log file: "/var/log/Xorg.0.log", Time: Fri Apr 25 10:20:03 2014
[    45.767] (==) Using config file: "/etc/X11/xorg.conf"
[    45.768] (==) Using system config directory "/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d"
[    46.283] (==) ServerLayout "layout"
[    46.283] (**) |-->Screen "nvidia" (0)
[    46.283] (**) |   |-->Monitor "<default monitor>"
[    46.284] (**) |   |-->Device "nvidia"
[    46.284] (==) No monitor specified for screen "nvidia".
Using a default monitor configuration.
[    46.284] (**) |-->Inactive Device "intel"
[    46.284] (==) Automatically adding devices
[    46.284] (==) Automatically enabling devices
[    46.284] (==) Automatically adding GPU devices
[    46.395] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/cyrillic" does not exist.
[    46.395]    Entry deleted from font path.
[    46.395] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/100dpi/" does not exist.
[    46.395]    Entry deleted from font path.
[    46.395] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/75dpi/" does not exist.
[    46.395]    Entry deleted from font path.
[    46.438] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/100dpi" does not exist.
[    46.438]    Entry deleted from font path.
[    46.438] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/75dpi" does not exist.
[    46.438]    Entry deleted from font path.
[    46.438] (==) FontPath set to:
/usr/share/fonts/X11/misc,
/usr/share/fonts/X11/Type1,
built-ins
[    46.438] (==) ModulePath set to "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/xorg/extra-modules,/usr/lib/xorg/extra-modules,/usr/lib/xorg/modules"
[    46.438] (II) The server relies on udev to provide the list of input devices.
If no devices become available, reconfigure udev or disable AutoAddDevices.
[    46.438] (II) Loader magic: 0x7f539332ed60
[    46.438] (II) Module ABI versions:
[    46.438]    X.Org ANSI C Emulation: 0.4
[    46.438]    X.Org Video Driver: 15.0
[    46.438]    X.Org XInput driver : 20.0
[    46.439]    X.Org Server Extension : 8.0
[    46.440] (II) xfree86: Adding drm device (/dev/dri/card1)
[    46.440] (II) xfree86: Adding drm device (/dev/dri/card0)
[    46.447] (--) PCI:*(0:0:2:0) 8086:0116:144d:c0a5 rev 9, Mem @ 0xf5400000/4194304, 0xc0000000/268435456, I/O @ 0x0000e000/64
[    46.447] (--) PCI: (0:1:0:0) 10de:0df4:144d:c0a5 rev 161, Mem @ 0xf4000000/16777216, 0xd0000000/268435456, 0xe0000000/33554432, I/O @ 0x0000d000/128, BIOS @ 0x????????/524288
[    46.491] Initializing built-in extension Generic Event Extension
[    46.491] Initializing built-in extension SHAPE
[    46.491] Initializing built-in extension MIT-SHM
[    46.491] Initializing built-in extension XInputExtension
[    46.491] Initializing built-in extension XTEST
[    46.491] Initializing built-in extension BIG-REQUESTS
[    46.491] Initializing built-in extension SYNC
[    46.491] Initializing built-in extension XKEYBOARD
[    46.492] Initializing built-in extension XC-MISC
[    46.492] Initializing built-in extension SECURITY
[    46.492] Initializing built-in extension XINERAMA
[    46.492] Initializing built-in extension XFIXES
[    46.492] Initializing built-in extension RENDER
[    46.492] Initializing built-in extension RANDR
[    46.492] Initializing built-in extension COMPOSITE
[    46.492] Initializing built-in extension DAMAGE
[    46.492] Initializing built-in extension MIT-SCREEN-SAVER
[    46.492] Initializing built-in extension DOUBLE-BUFFER
[    46.492] Initializing built-in extension RECORD
[    46.492] Initializing built-in extension DPMS
[    46.492] Initializing built-in extension Present
[    46.492] Initializing built-in extension DRI3
[    46.492] Initializing built-in extension X-Resource
[    46.493] Initializing built-in extension XVideo
[    46.493] Initializing built-in extension XVideo-MotionCompensation
[    46.493] Initializing built-in extension SELinux
[    46.493] Initializing built-in extension XFree86-VidModeExtension
[    46.493] Initializing built-in extension XFree86-DGA
[    46.493] Initializing built-in extension XFree86-DRI
[    46.493] Initializing built-in extension DRI2
[    46.493] (WW) "glamoregl" will not be loaded unless you've specified it to be loaded elsewhere.
[    46.493] (II) "glx" will be loaded by default.
[    46.493] (WW) "xmir" is not to be loaded by default. Skipping.
[    46.493] (II) LoadModule: "glx"
[    46.588] (II) Loading /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/xorg/extra-modules/libglx.so
[    50.389] (II) Module glx: vendor="NVIDIA Corporation"
[    50.389]    compiled for 4.0.2, module version = 1.0.0
[    50.389]    Module class: X.Org Server Extension
[    50.390] (II) NVIDIA GLX Module  331.67  Fri Apr  4 11:43:47 PDT 2014
[    50.425] Loading extension GLX
[    50.425] (II) LoadModule: "nvidia"
[    50.426] (II) Loading /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/xorg/extra-modules/nvidia_drv.so
[    51.029] (II) Module nvidia: vendor="NVIDIA Corporation"
[    51.029]    compiled for 4.0.2, module version = 1.0.0
[    51.029]    Module class: X.Org Video Driver
[    51.112] (II) LoadModule: "modesetting"
[    51.920] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/modesetting_drv.so
[    51.999] (II) Module modesetting: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[    51.999]    compiled for 1.15.0, module version = 0.8.1
[    51.999]    Module class: X.Org Video Driver
[    51.999]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 15.0
[    51.999] (II) NVIDIA dlloader X Driver  331.67  Fri Apr  4 11:24:40 PDT 2014
[    51.999] (II) NVIDIA Unified Driver for all Supported NVIDIA GPUs
[    52.098] (II) modesetting: Driver for Modesetting Kernel Drivers: kms
[    52.098] (++) using VT number 7

[    52.130] (II) Loading sub module "fb"
[    52.130] (II) LoadModule: "fb"
[    52.131] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/libfb.so
[    52.222] (II) Module fb: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[    52.222]    compiled for 1.15.1, module version = 1.0.0
[    52.222]    ABI class: X.Org ANSI C Emulation, version 0.4
[    52.222] (WW) Unresolved symbol: fbGetGCPrivateKey
[    52.222] (II) Loading sub module "wfb"
[    52.222] (II) LoadModule: "wfb"
[    52.223] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/libwfb.so
[    52.370] (II) Module wfb: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[    52.370]    compiled for 1.15.1, module version = 1.0.0
[    52.370]    ABI class: X.Org ANSI C Emulation, version 0.4
[    52.371] (II) Loading sub module "ramdac"
[    52.371] (II) LoadModule: "ramdac"
[    52.371] (II) Module "ramdac" already built-in
[    52.439] (II) modesetting(G0): using drv /dev/dri/card0
[    52.439] (II) NVIDIA(0): Creating default Display subsection in Screen section
"nvidia" for depth/fbbpp 24/32
[    52.439] (==) NVIDIA(0): Depth 24, (==) framebuffer bpp 32
[    52.440] (==) NVIDIA(0): RGB weight 888
[    52.440] (==) NVIDIA(0): Default visual is TrueColor
[    52.440] (==) NVIDIA(0): Using gamma correction (1.0, 1.0, 1.0)
[    52.445] (**) NVIDIA(0): Option "ConstrainCursor" "off"
[    52.446] (**) NVIDIA(0): Option "AllowEmptyInitialConfiguration" "on"
[    52.446] (**) NVIDIA(0): Enabling 2D acceleration
[    53.888] (WW) NVIDIA(0): Unable to read EDID for display device CRT-0
[    53.889] (II) NVIDIA(GPU-0): Found DRM driver nvidia-drm (20130102)
[    53.891] (II) NVIDIA(0): NVIDIA GPU GeForce GT 540M (GF108) at PCI:1:0:0 (GPU-0)
[    53.891] (--) NVIDIA(0): Memory: 2097152 kBytes
[    53.891] (--) NVIDIA(0): VideoBIOS: 70.08.58.00.03
[    53.891] (II) NVIDIA(0): Detected PCI Express Link width: 16X
[    53.891] (--) NVIDIA(0): Valid display device(s) on GeForce GT 540M at PCI:1:0:0
[    53.891] (--) NVIDIA(0):     CRT-0 (boot, connected)
[    53.891] (--) NVIDIA(0): CRT-0: 400.0 MHz maximum pixel clock
[    53.891] (**) NVIDIA(0): Using HorizSync/VertRefresh ranges from the EDID for display
[    53.891] (**) NVIDIA(0):     device CRT-0 (Using EDID frequencies has been enabled on
[    53.891] (**) NVIDIA(0):     all display devices.)
[    53.894] (==) NVIDIA(0): 
[    53.894] (==) NVIDIA(0): No modes were requested; the default mode "nvidia-auto-select"
[    53.894] (==) NVIDIA(0):     will be used as the requested mode.
[    53.894] (==) NVIDIA(0): 
[    53.894] (II) NVIDIA(0): Validated MetaModes:
[    53.894] (II) NVIDIA(0):     "CRT-0:nvidia-auto-select"
[    53.894] (II) NVIDIA(0): Virtual screen size determined to be 1024 x 768
[    53.896] (WW) NVIDIA(0): Unable to get display device CRT-0's EDID; cannot compute DPI
[    53.896] (WW) NVIDIA(0):     from CRT-0's EDID.
[    53.896] (==) NVIDIA(0): DPI set to (75, 75); computed from built-in default
[    53.896] (==) modesetting(G0): Depth 24, (==) framebuffer bpp 32
[    53.896] (==) modesetting(G0): RGB weight 888
[    53.896] (==) modesetting(G0): Default visual is TrueColor
[    53.896] (II) modesetting(G0): ShadowFB: preferred YES, enabled YES
[    53.896] (II) modesetting(G0): Output LVDS-1-0 has no monitor section
[    53.897] (II) modesetting(G0): Output VGA-1-0 has no monitor section
[    53.948] (II) modesetting(G0): Output HDMI-1-0 has no monitor section
[    53.996] (II) modesetting(G0): Output DisplayPort-1-0 has no monitor section
[    53.996] (II) modesetting(G0): EDID for output LVDS-1-0
[    53.996] (II) modesetting(G0): Manufacturer: SEC  Model: 544b  Serial#: 0
[    53.997] (II) modesetting(G0): Year: 2011  Week: 0
[    53.997] (II) modesetting(G0): EDID Version: 1.3
[    53.997] (II) modesetting(G0): Digital Display Input
[    53.997] (II) modesetting(G0): Max Image Size     [cm]: horiz.: 38  vert.: 21
[    53.997] (II) modesetting(G0): Gamma: 2.20
[    53.997] (II) modesetting(G0): No DPMS capabilities specified
[    53.997] (II) modesetting(G0): Supported color encodings: RGB 4:4:4 YCrCb 4:4:4 
[    53.997] (II) modesetting(G0): First detailed timing is preferred mode
[    53.997] (II) modesetting(G0): redX: 0.600 redY: 0.340   greenX: 0.310 greenY: 0.560
[    53.997] (II) modesetting(G0): blueX: 0.150 blueY: 0.130   whiteX: 0.313 whiteY: 0.329
[    53.997] (II) modesetting(G0): Manufacturer's mask: 0
[    53.997] (II) modesetting(G0): Supported detailed timing:
[    53.997] (II) modesetting(G0): clock: 107.8 MHz   Image Size:  382 x 214 mm
[    53.997] (II) modesetting(G0): h_active: 1600  h_sync: 1648  h_sync_end 1680 h_blank_end 1892 h_border: 0
[    53.997] (II) modesetting(G0): v_active: 900  v_sync: 902  v_sync_end 908 v_blanking: 950 v_border: 0
[    53.997] (II) modesetting(G0): Unknown vendor-specific block f
[    53.997] (II) modesetting(G0):  SAMSUNG
[    53.998] (II) modesetting(G0):  LTN173KT01C09
[    53.998] (II) modesetting(G0): EDID (in hex):
[    53.998] (II) modesetting(G0):  00ffffffffffff004ca34b5400000000
[    53.998] (II) modesetting(G0):  00150103802615780a859599574f8f26
[    53.998] (II) modesetting(G0):  21505400000001010101010101010101
[    53.998] (II) modesetting(G0):  010101010101202a4024618432303020
[    53.998] (II) modesetting(G0):  26007ed6100000190000000f00000000
[    53.998] (II) modesetting(G0):  00000000001eb4027400000000fe0053
[    53.998] (II) modesetting(G0):  414d53554e470a2020202020000000fe
[    53.998] (II) modesetting(G0):  004c544e3137334b5430314330390007
[    53.999] (II) modesetting(G0): Printing probed modes for output LVDS-1-0
***********removed************
[    54.002] (II) modesetting(G0): EDID for output VGA-1-0
[    54.052] (II) modesetting(G0): EDID for output HDMI-1-0
[    54.052] (II) modesetting(G0): Manufacturer: SAM  Model: 7d6  Serial#: 808465465
[    54.052] (II) modesetting(G0): Year: 2011  Week: 48
[    54.053] (II) modesetting(G0): EDID Version: 1.3
[    54.053] (II) modesetting(G0): Digital Display Input
[    54.053] (II) modesetting(G0): Max Image Size     [cm]: horiz.: 53  vert.: 30
[    54.053] (II) modesetting(G0): Gamma: 2.20
[    54.053] (II) modesetting(G0): DPMS capabilities: Off
[    54.053] (II) modesetting(G0): Supported color encodings: RGB 4:4:4 YCrCb 4:4:4 
[    54.053] (II) modesetting(G0): First detailed timing is preferred mode
[    54.053] (II) modesetting(G0): redX: 0.631 redY: 0.351   greenX: 0.334 greenY: 0.615
[    54.053] (II) modesetting(G0): blueX: 0.157 blueY: 0.051   whiteX: 0.312 whiteY: 0.329
[    54.053] (II) modesetting(G0): Supported established timings:
[    54.053] (II) modesetting(G0): 720x400@70Hz
[    54.053] (II) modesetting(G0): 640x480@60Hz
[    54.053] (II) modesetting(G0): 640x480@67Hz
[    54.053] (II) modesetting(G0): 640x480@72Hz
[    54.053] (II) modesetting(G0): 640x480@75Hz
[    54.053] (II) modesetting(G0): 800x600@56Hz
[    54.053] (II) modesetting(G0): 800x600@60Hz
[    54.053] (II) modesetting(G0): 800x600@72Hz
[    54.054] (II) modesetting(G0): 800x600@75Hz
[    54.054] (II) modesetting(G0): 832x624@75Hz
[    54.054] (II) modesetting(G0): 1024x768@60Hz
[    54.054] (II) modesetting(G0): 1024x768@70Hz
[    54.054] (II) modesetting(G0): 1024x768@75Hz
[    54.054] (II) modesetting(G0): 1280x1024@75Hz
[    54.054] (II) modesetting(G0): 1152x864@75Hz
[    54.054] (II) modesetting(G0): Manufacturer's mask: 0
[    54.054] (II) modesetting(G0): Supported standard timings:
[    54.054] (II) modesetting(G0): #0: hsize: 1152  vsize 864  refresh: 75  vid: 20337
[    54.054] (II) modesetting(G0): #1: hsize: 1280  vsize 800  refresh: 60  vid: 129
[    54.054] (II) modesetting(G0): #2: hsize: 1280  vsize 960  refresh: 60  vid: 16513
[    54.054] (II) modesetting(G0): #3: hsize: 1280  vsize 1024  refresh: 60  vid: 32897
[    54.054] (II) modesetting(G0): #4: hsize: 1440  vsize 900  refresh: 60  vid: 149
[    54.054] (II) modesetting(G0): #5: hsize: 1440  vsize 900  refresh: 75  vid: 3989
[    54.054] (II) modesetting(G0): #6: hsize: 1600  vsize 1200  refresh: 60  vid: 16553
[    54.054] (II) modesetting(G0): #7: hsize: 1680  vsize 1050  refresh: 60  vid: 179
[    54.054] (II) modesetting(G0): Supported detailed timing:
[    54.054] (II) modesetting(G0): clock: 148.5 MHz   Image Size:  531 x 299 mm
[    54.054] (II) modesetting(G0): h_active: 1920  h_sync: 2008  h_sync_end 2052 h_blank_end 2200 h_border: 0
[    54.054] (II) modesetting(G0): v_active: 1080  v_sync: 1084  v_sync_end 1089 v_blanking: 1125 v_border: 0
[    54.055] (II) modesetting(G0): Supported detailed timing:
[    54.055] (II) modesetting(G0): clock: 74.2 MHz   Image Size:  531 x 299 mm
[    54.055] (II) modesetting(G0): h_active: 1280  h_sync: 1390  h_sync_end 1430 h_blank_end 1650 h_border: 0
[    54.055] (II) modesetting(G0): v_active: 720  v_sync: 725  v_sync_end 730 v_blanking: 750 v_border: 0
[    54.055] (II) modesetting(G0): Ranges: V min: 50 V max: 75 Hz, H min: 31 H max: 81 kHz, PixClock max 175 MHz
[    54.055] (II) modesetting(G0): Monitor name: SA300/350/360
[    54.055] (II) modesetting(G0): Supported detailed timing:
[    54.055] (II) modesetting(G0): clock: 74.2 MHz   Image Size:  531 x 299 mm
[    54.055] (II) modesetting(G0): h_active: 1920  h_sync: 2448  h_sync_end 2492 h_blank_end 2640 h_border: 0
[    54.055] (II) modesetting(G0): v_active: 540  v_sync: 542  v_sync_end 547 v_blanking: 562 v_border: 0
[    54.055] (II) modesetting(G0): Supported detailed timing:
[    54.055] (II) modesetting(G0): clock: 74.2 MHz   Image Size:  531 x 299 mm
[    54.055] (II) modesetting(G0): h_active: 1920  h_sync: 2008  h_sync_end 2052 h_blank_end 2200 h_border: 0
[    54.055] (II) modesetting(G0): v_active: 540  v_sync: 542  v_sync_end 547 v_blanking: 562 v_border: 0
[    54.055] (II) modesetting(G0): Supported detailed timing:
[    54.055] (II) modesetting(G0): clock: 74.2 MHz   Image Size:  531 x 299 mm
[    54.056] (II) modesetting(G0): h_active: 1280  h_sync: 1720  h_sync_end 1760 h_blank_end 1980 h_border: 0
[    54.056] (II) modesetting(G0): v_active: 720  v_sync: 725  v_sync_end 730 v_blanking: 750 v_border: 0
[    54.056] (II) modesetting(G0): Supported detailed timing:
[    54.056] (II) modesetting(G0): clock: 27.0 MHz   Image Size:  531 x 299 mm
[    54.056] (II) modesetting(G0): h_active: 720  h_sync: 732  h_sync_end 796 h_blank_end 864 h_border: 0
[    54.056] (II) modesetting(G0): v_active: 576  v_sync: 581  v_sync_end 586 v_blanking: 625 v_border: 0
[    54.056] (II) modesetting(G0): Supported detailed timing:
[    54.056] (II) modesetting(G0): clock: 27.0 MHz   Image Size:  531 x 299 mm
[    54.056] (II) modesetting(G0): h_active: 720  h_sync: 736  h_sync_end 798 h_blank_end 858 h_border: 0
[    54.056] (II) modesetting(G0): v_active: 480  v_sync: 489  v_sync_end 495 v_blanking: 525 v_border: 0
[    54.056] (II) modesetting(G0): Number of EDID sections to follow: 1
[    54.056] (II) modesetting(G0): EDID (in hex):
[    54.056] (II) modesetting(G0):  00ffffffffffff004c2dd60739343030
[    54.056] (II) modesetting(G0):  3015010380351e782aba41a159559d28
[    54.056] (II) modesetting(G0):  0d5054bfef80714f8100814081809500
[    54.056] (II) modesetting(G0):  950fa940b300023a801871382d40582c
[    54.057] (II) modesetting(G0):  4500132b2100001e011d007251d01e20
[    54.057] (II) modesetting(G0):  6e285500132b2100001e000000fd0032
[    54.057] (II) modesetting(G0):  4b1f5111000a202020202020000000fc
[    54.057] (II) modesetting(G0):  0053413330302f3335302f3336300160
[    54.057] (II) modesetting(G0):  020313b14890041f051413120365030c
[    54.057] (II) modesetting(G0):  001000011d80d0721c1620102c258013
[    54.057] (II) modesetting(G0):  2b2100009e011d8018711c1620582c25
[    54.057] (II) modesetting(G0):  00132b2100009e011d00bc52d01e20b8
[    54.057] (II) modesetting(G0):  285540132b2100001e8c0ad090204031
[    54.057] (II) modesetting(G0):  200c405500132b210000188c0ad08a20
[    54.057] (II) modesetting(G0):  e02d10103e9600132b21000018000000
[    54.057] (II) modesetting(G0):  000000000000000000000000000000d5
[    54.057] (II) modesetting(G0): Printing probed modes for output HDMI-1-0
[    54.057] (II) modesetting(G0): Modeline "1920x1080"x60.0  148.50  1920 2008 2052 2200  1080 1084 1089 1125 +hsync +vsync (67.5 kHz eP)
[    54.057] (II) modesetting(G0): Modeline "1920x1080"x50.0  148.50  1920 2448 2492 2640  1080 1084 1089 1125 +hsync +vsync (56.2 kHz e)
[    54.057] (II) modesetting(G0): Modeline "1920x1080"x59.9  148.35  1920 2008 2052 2200  1080 1084 1089 1125 +hsync +vsync (67.4 kHz e)
[    54.057] (II) modesetting(G0): Modeline "1920x1080i"x60.0   74.25  1920 2008 2052 2200  1080 1084 1094 1125 interlace +hsync +vsync (33.8 kHz e)
[    54.058] (II) modesetting(G0): Modeline "1920x1080i"x50.0   74.25  1920 2448 2492 2640  1080 1084 1094 1125 interlace +hsync +vsync (28.1 kHz e)
[    54.058] (II) modesetting(G0): Modeline "1920x1080i"x59.9   74.18  1920 2008 2052 2200  1080 1084 1094 1125 interlace +hsync +vsync (33.7 kHz e)
[    54.058] (II) modesetting(G0): Modeline "1600x1200"x60.0  162.00  1600 1664 1856 2160  1200 1201 1204 1250 +hsync +vsync (75.0 kHz e)
[    54.058] (II) modesetting(G0): Modeline "1680x1050"x59.9  119.00  1680 1728 1760 1840  1050 1053 1059 1080 +hsync -vsync (64.7 kHz e)
[    54.058] (II) modesetting(G0): Modeline "1280x1024"x75.0  135.00  1280 1296 1440 1688  1024 1025 1028 1066 +hsync +vsync (80.0 kHz e)
[    54.058] (II) modesetting(G0): Modeline "1280x1024"x60.0  108.00  1280 1328 1440 1688  1024 1025 1028 1066 +hsync +vsync (64.0 kHz e)
[    54.058] (II) modesetting(G0): Modeline "1440x900"x75.0  136.75  1440 1536 1688 1936  900 903 909 942 -hsync +vsync (70.6 kHz e)
[    54.058] (II) modesetting(G0): Modeline "1440x900"x59.9   88.75  1440 1488 1520 1600  900 903 909 926 +hsync -vsync (55.5 kHz e)
[    54.058] (II) modesetting(G0): Modeline "1280x960"x60.0  108.00  1280 1376 1488 1800  960 961 964 1000 +hsync +vsync (60.0 kHz e)
[    54.058] (II) modesetting(G0): Modeline "1280x800"x59.9   71.00  1280 1328 1360 1440  800 803 809 823 +hsync -vsync (49.3 kHz e)
[    54.058] (II) modesetting(G0): Modeline "1152x864"x75.0  108.00  1152 1216 1344 1600  864 865 868 900 +hsync +vsync (67.5 kHz e)
[    54.058] (II) modesetting(G0): Modeline "1280x720"x60.0   74.25  1280 1390 1430 1650  720 725 730 750 +hsync +vsync (45.0 kHz e)
[    54.058] (II) modesetting(G0): Modeline "1280x720"x50.0   74.25  1280 1720 1760 1980  720 725 730 750 +hsync +vsync (37.5 kHz e)
[    54.058] (II) modesetting(G0): Modeline "1280x720"x59.9   74.18  1280 1390 1430 1650  720 725 730 750 +hsync +vsync (45.0 kHz e)
[    54.058] (II) modesetting(G0): Modeline "1024x768"x75.1   78.80  1024 1040 1136 1312  768 769 772 800 +hsync +vsync (60.1 kHz e)
[    54.058] (II) modesetting(G0): Modeline "1024x768"x70.1   75.00  1024 1048 1184 1328  768 771 777 806 -hsync -vsync (56.5 kHz e)
[    54.058] (II) modesetting(G0): Modeline "1024x768"x60.0   65.00  1024 1048 1184 1344  768 771 777 806 -hsync -vsync (48.4 kHz e)
[    54.058] (II) modesetting(G0): Modeline "832x624"x74.6   57.28  832 864 928 1152  624 625 628 667 -hsync -vsync (49.7 kHz e)
[    54.059] (II) modesetting(G0): Modeline "800x600"x72.2   50.00  800 856 976 1040  600 637 643 666 +hsync +vsync (48.1 kHz e)
[    54.059] (II) modesetting(G0): Modeline "800x600"x75.0   49.50  800 816 896 1056  600 601 604 625 +hsync +vsync (46.9 kHz e)
[    54.059] (II) modesetting(G0): Modeline "800x600"x60.3   40.00  800 840 968 1056  600 601 605 628 +hsync +vsync (37.9 kHz e)
[    54.059] (II) modesetting(G0): Modeline "800x600"x56.2   36.00  800 824 896 1024  600 601 603 625 +hsync +vsync (35.2 kHz e)
[    54.059] (II) modesetting(G0): Modeline "720x576"x50.0   27.00  720 732 796 864  576 581 586 625 -hsync -vsync (31.2 kHz e)
[    54.059] (II) modesetting(G0): Modeline "720x480"x60.0   27.03  720 736 798 858  480 489 495 525 -hsync -vsync (31.5 kHz e)
[    54.059] (II) modesetting(G0): Modeline "720x480"x59.9   27.00  720 736 798 858  480 489 495 525 -hsync -vsync (31.5 kHz e)
[    54.059] (II) modesetting(G0): Modeline "640x480"x75.0   31.50  640 656 720 840  480 481 484 500 -hsync -vsync (37.5 kHz e)
[    54.059] (II) modesetting(G0): Modeline "640x480"x72.8   31.50  640 664 704 832  480 489 491 520 -hsync -vsync (37.9 kHz e)
[    54.059] (II) modesetting(G0): Modeline "640x480"x66.7   30.24  640 704 768 864  480 483 486 525 -hsync -vsync (35.0 kHz e)
[    54.059] (II) modesetting(G0): Modeline "640x480"x60.0   25.20  640 656 752 800  480 490 492 525 -hsync -vsync (31.5 kHz e)
[    54.059] (II) modesetting(G0): Modeline "640x480"x59.9   25.18  640 656 752 800  480 490 492 525 -hsync -vsync (31.5 kHz e)
[    54.059] (II) modesetting(G0): Modeline "720x400"x70.1   28.32  720 738 846 900  400 412 414 449 -hsync +vsync (31.5 kHz e)
[    54.108] (II) modesetting(G0): EDID for output DisplayPort-1-0
[    54.108] (II) modesetting(G0): Using default gamma of (1.0, 1.0, 1.0) unless otherwise stated.
[    54.108] (==) modesetting(G0): DPI set to (96, 96)
[    54.108] (II) Loading sub module "fb"
[    54.108] (II) LoadModule: "fb"
[    54.109] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/libfb.so
[    54.109] (II) Module fb: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[    54.109]    compiled for 1.15.1, module version = 1.0.0
[    54.109]    ABI class: X.Org ANSI C Emulation, version 0.4
[    54.109] (II) Loading sub module "shadow"
[    54.109] (II) LoadModule: "shadow"
[    54.110] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/libshadow.so
[    54.192] (II) Module shadow: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[    54.192]    compiled for 1.15.1, module version = 1.1.0
[    54.192]    ABI class: X.Org ANSI C Emulation, version 0.4
[    54.192] (--) Depth 24 pixmap format is 32 bpp
[    54.285] (==) modesetting(G0): Backing store enabled
[    54.286] (==) modesetting(G0): Silken mouse enabled
[    54.286] (II) modesetting(G0): RandR 1.2 enabled, ignore the following RandR disabled message.
[    54.288] (==) modesetting(G0): DPMS enabled
[    54.288] (WW) modesetting(G0): Option "AllowEmptyInitialConfiguration" is not used
[    54.921] (II) NVIDIA: Using 3072.00 MB of virtual memory for indirect memory
[    54.921] (II) NVIDIA:     access.
[    54.946] (II) NVIDIA(0): Setting mode "CRT-0:nvidia-auto-select"
[    62.812] (EE) 
Fatal server error:
[    62.812] (EE) NVIDIA: A GPU exception occurred during X server initialization(EE) 
[    62.812] (EE) 
Please consult the The X.Org Foundation support 
 at http://wiki.x.org
for help. 
[    62.812] (EE) Please also check the log file at "/var/log/Xorg.0.log" for additional information.
[    62.812] (EE) 
[    63.200] (EE) Server terminated with error (1). Closing log file.
```

Finally, here is the relevant Xorg.conf generated by nvidia

```
Section "ServerLayout"
    Identifier "layout"
    Screen 0 "nvidia"
    Inactive "intel"
EndSection

Section "Device"
    Identifier "intel"
    Driver "modesetting"
    BusID "PCI:0@0:2:0"
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier "intel"
    Device "intel"
EndSection

Section "Device"
    Identifier "nvidia"
    Driver "nvidia"
    BusID "PCI:1@0:0:0"
    Option "ConstrainCursor" "off"
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier "nvidia"
    Device "nvidia"
    Option "AllowEmptyInitialConfiguration" "on"
EndSection
```

Thanks in advance for your help everyone. Do let me know if you need any more information.

Ant

Comment: A little more information for you: 
    1) I tried the nvidia-337 drivers just now, with exactly the same result. 
    2) I am not too fussed about having switchable graphics and would be happy to just used the Nvidia card all the time (I tried doing this in the BIOS but didn't have the option to select it). Obviously if there is a solution which allows switchable graphics that would be ideal, however!

Comment: Is their an option in your BIOS to select which video card enables first? This is fairly common among quality manufacturers and it might help to activate the GeForce GT 540M first before the onboard Intel since you can't choose it exclusively.

Comment: Hi, thanks for replying. I had a look through the BIOS and couldn't find any options for selecting a graphics card at all. That said, I'm not particularly knowledgeable about using the BIOS, so if anyone has any suggestions specific for my system that would be helpful also!

Comment: What is the make and model of your system?

Comment: It is a Samsung RF711

Comment: This one? -> RF Series RF711-S02 Notebook Intel Core i7 2630QM (2.00GHz) 4GB Memory 750GB HDD NVIDIA GeForce GT 540M w/ NVIDIA Optimus ...

Comment: If so, there is a manual at http://www.samsung.com/us/support/owners/product/NP-RF711-S02US

Comment: Thanks, I'll check that out and see if I can find an option to switch to the discrete card.

Comment: I haven't been able to find any way to switch to the discrete card via the BIOS.

Comment: I dont know if I understand you. Do you want Intel card runs by default?

Comment: Currently I can't use the Nvidia card at all, and I would like to be able to do that. Ideally I'd be able to choose which card I use for each program I run (like Bumblebee allows you to do) but I'd be happy as long as I can use the Nvidia card, even if it's used by default for everything.

Comment: Do you still have this problem or were you able to resolve it? Thank you!

Comment: Unfortunately, I was unable to resolve the issue!

Answer (score 6):

You can try the [nvidia-prime](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/nvidia-prime) package, to have a better support of the Nvidia Optimus Technology.

The first step is to clean-up a little bit your system with :

```
sudo apt-get purge bumblebee* primus libvdpau-va-gl1
```

And we install the nvidia driver and nvidia-prime :

```
sudo apt-get install nvidia-331 nvidia-prime mesa-utils
```

If you want the grapical acceleration for HD videos, you can install :

```
sudo apt-get install vdpau-va-driver
```

Then reboot your system. And go to 'nvidia-settings' to check under the nvidia-prime section if you can switch card.

[image: Nvidia-Prime Settings. Source : webupd8.org]

You can also add an applet for unity to simply switch between cards : prime-indicator

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:nilarimogard/webupd8
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install prime-indicator
sudo reboot
```

[More info about the prime-indicator.](https://github.com/beidl/prime-indicator)

Comment: Thanks very much! I'll try this shortly and let you know how I get on.

Comment: I just tried this, but had the same problem as in the original question: booted to low graphics mode and the Xorg log file showed the same error.

Comment: works like a charm :-) thx!

Answer (score 0):

Based on your xorg.conf it appears you are using the nvidia and not the Intel, hence:

Section "ServerLayout"

Identifier "layout"

**Screen 0 "nvidia"**

**Inactive "intel"**

Everything I can find indicates that the driver is broken in this configuration and you are better off just using the Intel. I would contact the manufacturer [here](http://www.samsung.com/us/support/) and ask about a BIOS update that would allow the functionality that you desire.

source: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1699939

Comment: Well, it is clearly trying to use the nvidia card, but it boots to low graphics mode, outputting the Xorg log file given above.

Comment: I have edited my answer

Comment: Are you maybe using the `xorg-edgers` PPA? I got low graphics mode too when I'm using NVIDIA with their drivers. Try removing all NVIDIA stuff (`sudo apt-get --purge remove nvidia* && apt-get --purge autoremove`, also make sure `bumblebee` is completely removed as well), remove their PPA and install `nvida-current` (`sudo apt-get install nvidia-current`). Now you can switch using NVIDIA's CP or using `sudo prime-select nvidia/intel`.

Comment: I will try this.

Answer (score 0):

I too had same issues. Installing bumblebee will solve your issues most probably. Here

https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Bumblebee

Comment: I haven't managed to get bumblebee to work at all either, after multiple attempts. Thanks though!