# How to purge and reinstall bumblebee completely?

Tags: nvidia-optimus, bumblebee

I have had bumblebee working since 13.04. It took me some messing around though and now on 14.04 it is not working anymore.

How can I purge it completely and reinstall it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To remove bumblebee completely

```
sudo apt-get install ppa-purge
sudo ppa-purge ppa:bumblebee/stable
sudo apt-get purge bumblebee
```

To reinstall bumblebee (and bumblebee ui) follow this 
[How to set up nVidia Optimus/Bumblebee in 14.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/452556/how-to-set-up-nvidia-optimus-bumblebee-in-14-04)

Answer (score 1):

I recommend looking into installing the proprietary drivers and nvidia-prime if you are using 14.04. It finally supports optimus and you can switch your graphics card via an additional indicator. For me the performance is much better using nvidia-prime.
In this thread the installation is explained quite well: [How do I get switchable graphics to work on my Samsung RF711 With Intel HD & GeForce 540M Graphics cards on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS](https://askubuntu.com/questions/455124/how-do-i-get-switchable-graphics-to-work-on-my-samsung-rf711-with-intel-hd-gef/468645#468645)