# how to boot USB in virtualbox?

Tags: usb, virtualbox

I press F12 repeatedly to select boot device.

AHCI controller:

- Hard disk

Other boot devices:

- floppy
- CD
- LAN
- continue booting

I followed [How to boot from a USB drive in VirtualBox?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/693719/how-to-boot-from-a-usb-drive-in-virtual) box and the commands of vbox users to add it.
but is plop boot manager compulsory?

I have guest-additions and virtualbox-extension pack installed and even my **san disk** lists in the settings menu -> USB .

Comment: yes, it is a live iso that PC boots fine. should i specify a port number? but even then, in the boot screen USB should be listed. u) usb like that.

Comment: Please *carefully* read the first answer listed on that page (the answer that begins with "VirtualBox itself does not support booting from a USB device."):  http://askubuntu.com/questions/693719/how-to-boot-from-a-usb-drive-in-virtualbox

Comment: yes i earlier read that http://askubuntu.com/questions/693719/how-to-boot-from-a-usb-drive-in-virtualbox

Comment: but my question is will i be forced to use plop boot manager?

Comment: i followed already the advic of Terrance from your link yesterday, but my question is is plop booter compulsory?

Comment: Please see the answer I just posted.

Comment: Since not all of the answers of the linked question involve the Plop boot manager I conclude that its not required. I'm voting to close this question as a duplicate because both the original and the follow-up question are answered there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Virtualbox does not support booting directly from USB.** However, it does support booting directly from .iso files. So there are two options:

1) You can boot from a Plop Boot Manager .iso (or something like it), then use Plop to boot from your USB drive (see [How to boot from a USB drive in VirtualBox?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/693719/how-to-boot-from-a-usb-drive-in-virtualbox)); or

2) Boot from a different .iso file within virtualbox. For example, if you're trying to install Ubuntu in Virtualbox with an Ubuntu USB stick, you can *skip the usb stick completely*. Instead, mount the Ubuntu .iso file as a "virtual DVD drive" to boot from it directly.

Comment: genius, right, now i will use the iso's. so the terrance advice was for iso not USB. i didnt knew that. thx.