# I have a vbox extension virtual machine instead of vdi. How should I resize storage of vbox?

Tags: partitioning, virtualbox

I'm trying to install Ubuntu on the virtual box using USB. My primary OS is also Ubuntu. When I'm booting, it's giving me this problem:
[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vhxHD.png)

So, I'm trying to find a way to resize the storage. I came across this command: `VBoxManage modifyhd YOUR_HARD_DISK.vdi --resize SIZE_IN_MB`
, but this only works if the image extension is vdi.

In my system, under *Virtual box image folder*, it's shows Ubuntu.vbox instead of Ubuntu.vdi.

Answer (score 0):

The `.vbox` is an xml file describing the properties of the VM, not the virtual hard drive.
In the .vbox file you can find the Virtual hard drive properties in the *HardDisks* sections. You can also find the virtual Hard drive properties (including file name and location) in the VirtualBox GUI showing the VM properties.

Available Virtual hard drive extensions are : VDI|VMDK|VHD
Only VDI and VHD can be resized (expanded)

- Open virtualbox gui
- Display the *Virtual media manager* <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>
- Find you virtual Hard Drive
-- If it is a VDI or VHD file you can resize it with a command like that:
`vboxmanage modifymedium --resize <newSizeInMegabytes> /path/to/file.vdi`
-- If it is VMDK file, you will have to create a new Virtual hard drive file or clone the existing and change the file type.
You can do both from the VirtualBox media manager or from CLI with `vboxmanage`. And then attach the new drive to the VM.

Get more information:
https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch08.html#vboxmanage-createmedium

Comment: Thanks for clearing my vbox doubt :)

Answer (score 0):

After posting this question, I researched more and thanks to [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1159611/977115), I understood the difference of vdi and vbox.

If someone is stuck with the storage issue while booting from USB, and you've made a vmdk extension file e.g. *usb.vmdk*, create an iso instead of vmdk file from the bootable USB.

This answer will help you to create iso from bootable usb.

```
dd if=/dev/sdc of=myusbkey.iso
```

You have to replace the sdc with your usb disk name. You can find out that by using: `sudo lsblk`

The original answer that helped me is [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/848865/977115).