# Does Ubuntu remember the /dev/sdXX it was installed to or will it recognize it as being run from /dev/sdXY?

Tags: boot, usb, virtualization

New Ubuntu asker here,

If I install Ubuntu in a VM and write the VHD to a USB, will it request data from the location it was installed to (/dev/sdXX) or the port it boots from (/dev/sdXY)? For reasons I can't explain, I can't install it directly to a USB. I've tried searching but have only found guides on how to install it directly to the USB, however I have seen videos of what I am describing from 2-5 years ago. Does the Ubuntu install system from 5 years ago still work the same today?

Comment: Done properly, it will use the drive it boots from, the USB. However, based upon the second half your description, you might not be doing it properly.

Comment: The drive designation can change between reboots causing the `/dev/sdXX` to change.   I did write up this answer a while ago kind of showing that:  https://askubuntu.com/a/693729/231142

Comment: The thing is (as ridiculous as it sounds), my device has only one working USB port.

Comment: I keep a Windows virtual machine on USB. When I plug it into a different computer I need to create a virtual machine with "Use an existing virtual hard disk file". which only takes seconds.