# Run Ubuntu from a USB in a VM

Tags: partitioning, usb, virtualbox, virtualization, 19.04

I have Ubuntu installed in a partition of a USB and I would like to know if it could be run from within a VM so I dont have to constantly restart my computer to swap between Ubuntu and Windows.

I've tried to follow the instructions in [this post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/693719/how-to-boot-from-a-usb-drive-in-virtualbox) but I there is no bootable drive found when I try to select my USB

Comment: I know from direct experience that Plop Boot Manager can boot a VMware Workstation or Player virtual machine from a device connected to a USB 2.0 port. Doesn't work if the device is connected to a USB 3.0 port. No idea about other hypervisors. On the other hand, if a virtual machine is all you need that why not actually *install* Ubuntu on it? Bootable flash drives are for physical computers.

Comment: @AlexP think my laptop only has USB 3.0 ports

Comment: Doesn't matter if the port is blue, the connection must be USB 2.0. So, for example, you can get a dirt cheap USB 2.0 stick. (USB 3.0 stick in a black port - works. USB 2.0 stick in a blue port - works. USB 3.0 stick in a blue port - doesn't work.) But again, it's a VM -- why not *install* Ubuntu on it?

Comment: Ah that would be the issue, my USB is 3.0. What are you meaning by installing Ubuntu on it? I installed ubuntu directly onto the USB

Comment: Install Ubuntu on the virtual disk of the VM. Download ISO image, boot VM from ISO image. You want a 25 or 30 GB virtual disk.

Comment: Merely *selecting* a USB stick does not work - you must follow the instructions in the post you linked to and create a chainloader.