# Loading another Ubuntu within Ubuntu?

Tags: boot, 18.04, virtualbox, 20.04, chroot

I have an Ubuntu OS on a separate HDD. Is it possible to load that Ubuntu system with full Desktop GUI within my current running Ubuntu machine?

I look for something like

- `chroot` but full desktop access rather than shell only.
- `VirtualBox` but loading Ubuntu from its standard folders (e.g., a bootable USB stick) rather than an image.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve by doing this? There might be a better way to accomplish it.

Comment: You should be able to boot that drive in VirtualBox.  It is along the same lines as an answer I wrote a while back where you create a raw vmdk that points to your other Ubuntu drive.  See:  https://askubuntu.com/a/693729/231142

Comment: @user535733 I want to be able to access my old Ubuntu machine (now on a separate disk) while using the current one.

Comment: "Access" implies you just want your data. That's easy; takes a few minutes to learn. Running a bootable USB stick or .iso using KVM will take you about a half-day to learn. Booting a complete GUI from a different installed partition on your hard drive using KVM will take you most of a day. Look up any of the many KVM tutorials to get started. You could also use VirtualBox or LXD 3.0 or higher if you are already familiar with them.

Comment: MultiBootUSB, http://multibootusb.org/, has an option to run Live USB sticks from within Windows or Ubuntu. Not sure it is working with 20.04 yet.